# How to structure models, beans, controllers, and views for a different jsp pages but reside in to one table in a database?

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc, architecture, spring-webflow

This is a new project we are doing using **Spring MVC 2.5, jsp , Java7, Ajax, and HTML5.** On my part I am going to have have 7-10 jsp pages which contain one form each.These pages are sequential. i.e One have to pass the first page successfuly to go to the second and pass the second page to go to the third and so on.

The data in order to be persisted, one has to get to the last page (after passing the rest successfully) and confirm the information is correct. Once the user confirms, I have to persist all the data stored in a bean or session (All or none). **No incomplete data should be persisted.** Let's call our database table "employee"

I am new to Spring MVC but got the idea and implemented the page flow using a controller.

My question is should I need to have one model class or bean to store all the data, or use session to store each pages information and keep it in the session until it gets persisted?

Or its better to have one model class, but multiple controller/bean to control the data flow from each page. Which one  do you recommend? Is there any design pattern already implemented to answer my question? If you have a better idea please feel free to discuss your idea.

Comment: This sounds like a better match for Spring Webflow, actually (http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow) which has a built-in scope called flowScope where you store things that should exist during the entire sequence and be persisted at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches as you have already mentioned. Which one to use depends on the datasize and other requirements, for example, whether the user can come back later and continue from where he left. The model and controller need not be just one. It can be designed appropriately.

a) **Store data from each screen in the session:**

- Pros: Unnecessary data is not persisted to db. Can manipulate data from within the session when user traverses back and forth on the screens and hence faster.
- Cons of this approach: Too much information in the session can cause memory issues. May not be very helpful during session failover.The user cannot log back in and continue from where the user left, if this functionality is required.

b) **Persist each screen data as the user moves on:**

- Pros: Session is lighter, so only minimum relevant information is stored in the session. User can log back in and continue from where the user left.
  A separate inprogress db tables can be used to store this information and only on final submit insert/update the data into the actual tables, else the db would contain a lot of unsubmitted data. This way the inprogress db can be cleaned up periodically.
- Cons: Need to make db calls to persist and retrieve for every screen, even though it may not be submitted by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about your use of the HTTP session for storing the state of the forms.

> or use session to store each pages information and keep it in the
>   session until it gets persisted?

because of this requirement:

> No incomplete data should be persisted

As for

> should I need to have one model class or bean to store all the data

You can model this as you see fit. Perhaps a model to represent the flow and then an object for each page. Depends on how the data is split across the pages.

Although as noted in a comment above you might be able to make use of WebFlow to achieve this. However that is ultimately just a lightweight framework over Spring MVC.